# google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent('XXXX') issue

Tags: google-api

Trying to get some help with this code block. 
My script first looks for a specific folder and if it exists the pass the id of the folder to the google.picker.DocsUploadView(). When I hard-code the value of setParent to 'gdfid', everything works well. On the other hand, I need the code to be parameterized.

thanks in advance for any assistance

Pete

here's my code:

```
  var gdfid;

  function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        "corpora": "user",
        "spaces": "drive",
        "fields": "files(id,name)",
        "q": "name = 'myUploads"
      }).then(function(response) {
             console.log( response.result.files.length );
            if (response.result.files.length > 0) {
                console.log( response.result );
                gdfid = response.result.files[0].id;
            }
        //alert('Folder ID: ' + gdfid);
      });
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
      setTitle('Upload to myPratt Folder').
      enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
      enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN).
      addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().
          setIncludeFolders(false).
          setParent('gdfid')). //tried with and without quotes
          setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
          setCallback(pickerCallback).
          build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `.then{}` promise code block. I've had lots of trouble with them. The problem is that the `.then{}` code block has a closed scope.

When you assign `gdfid = response.result.files[0].id;` it's assumed that it is changing the global variable. But it isn't. It's only creating a local version of gdfid.

I ran around in circles myself for ages trying to figure out how to save external state information from within a `.then{}` block. Any possible solutions I came up with, were invariably no better than the callback hell that promises were supposed to solve in the first place. I even had problems returning objects out from it. I think the problem is that a `.then{}` block needs to run from a returned promise. Promises are actually functions earmarked to run in the future. They are subject to scoping restrictions, because they cannot make assumptions about the state of code outside the function. And they only pass object/variables a certain way. Trying to assign globals or returning data the regular way, from inside the `.then{}` block, is fraught with problems. It will often leave you tearing your hair out.

Try refactoring your code into a function with async/await, and use a try-catch statement to capture promise fails (Note: The try-catch statement still suffers from the global variable isolation problem, but at least it seems to be solely within the catch block. This is only an issue when an error occurs). I find async await much cleaner and easier to understand, and the scoping of variables works more intuitively.

In your case you could rewrite the code thus:

```
function async createPicker() {
    var gdfid;
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        try {
            var response = await gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                "corpora": "user",
                "spaces": "drive",
                "fields": "files(id,name)",
                "q": "name = 'myUploads"
            });
            console.log( response.result.files.length );
            if (response.result.files.length > 0) {
                console.log( response.result );
                gdfid = response.result.files[0].id;
            }
            //alert('Folder ID: ' + gdfid);
            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .setTitle('Upload to myPratt Folder')
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView()
                .setIncludeFolders(false)
                .setParent(gdfid)) //tried with and without quotes
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error displaying file list");
        }
    };
}
```

The only real difference here, is the `await` in front of the `gapi.client.drive.files`
function forces the code to wait for a callback to assign the response variable. This is not too much of a slowdown issue when running single popup UI elements that the user interacts with.

The gdfid variable is no longer global. In fact you don't even need it. You could setParent directly from the response variable.